# angular version mismatch issue when creating ionic 6 project

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, angular13, ionic6, angular14

When I am creating IONIC 6 Project it comes with angular version 14 but in the "devDependencies" entry i can see the "@angular-eslint/builder, eslint-plugin, eslint-plugin-template & template-parser" has version 13 entries, which causes a problem when I am running on livereload using command "ionic cordova run android -l" it show's an error:

"This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^13.0.0, but Angular version 14.0.6 was found instead".

I tried upgrading DEV DEPENDENCIES "builder, eslint-plugin, eslint-plugin-template, template-parser" to 14 but still facing the same error when running Command "ionic cordova run android -l"..

I tried UPGRADING my angular version 13 to 14 multiple times yet when I am creating IONIC 6 Project by default its taking angular version 14 but in the "DEV DEPENDENCIES", "builder, eslint-plugin, eslint-plugin-template, template-parser" has the entries of version 13. WHAT I WANT IS WHEN I CREATE IONIC 6 PROJECT "DEV DEPENDENCIES ENTRY" MUST BE 14 NOT 13

MY MAIN PROBLEM IS WHEN I AM RUNNIGN COMMAND "ionic cordova run android -l" ITS SHOW'S ERROR ("This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^13.0.0, but Angular version 14.0.6 was found instead".)

My Machines installed versions:
NPM: 8
Node: 16
Angular: 14
Ionic: 6
Cordova: 10

I have attached screenshot below please have a look:

[image]